# setTickLabelRotation(-90) doesn't work for horizontal CategoryAxis

Tags: java, javafx-2

My labels are about 12 characters long. A rotation of +90° automatically overrules the argument of setTickLabelRotation. Thus the labels are best readable from left. 
But I need them to be best readable from right.

[image: Labels readable from left side]

Comment: which version of javaFX are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.2.21-b11

Comment: I changed to version 2.2.55-b13: Same result.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely a bug in JavaFX 2.2, though there is no such a problem in JavaFX 8.

The workaround , as per comment, is to override the value on every change of it:

```
xAxis.tickLabelRotationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(-90);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks; it works. But the first change of window size recreates the "standard" behavior. Thus I'll change to JavaFX 8.